# 3D-2D Point correspondences for Homography matrix computation in camera calibration

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I have been trying to understand the concepts behind camera calibration but have been stuck for a while now. I plan on implementing Zhang's camera calibration algorithm (without using Opencv library functions). Now as per my understanding in order to compute camera intrinsic parameters I need to compute the Homography matrix 'H' (H = K [R | t]) which requires 3D-2D point correspondences for it's computation (since each pt. correspondence results in 2 eqs. we would need at least 6 for the 12 unknowns) followed by SVD of the matrix in order to get the camera matrix 'K'. Now the part which has been hard for me is to get these 3D-2D pt. correspondences. Please correct me if i am wrong here but does it mean I need to find the corners using Harris corner detection algorithm leading to the chessboard corners in pixel coordinates and I set the origin (0,0) for the 3D physical point as some point on the chessboard pattern leading to a pt. correspondence where I have let's say some (x',y') as image coordinates in pixels and (X,Y) as physical coordinates with for example the origin at the center of the board?

**EDIT:**

Below is a code snippet for calculating normalized cross correlation in order to get point correspondences between image corner coordinates (found by harris corner detection algo.) and self defined world corner coordinates.

```
void ncc(Mat &img, vector< vector<Point3f> >phy_corners, vector< vector<Point2f> >img_corners)
{

    float ncc       = 0;
    Size window;
    window.width    = 5;
    window.height   = 5;
    int pad_y       = (window.width - 1)  + img.cols;
    int pad_x       = (window.height - 1) + img.rows;
    int idx_y       = (window.height - 1) / 2;
    int idx_x       = (window.width - 1)  / 2;

    Mat T           = Mat::zeros(5*50+2, 8*50+2 , CV_32FC1);
    Mat I           = Mat::zeros(pad_x, pad_y, CV_32FC1);
    Mat NCC         = Mat::zeros(img.size(), CV_32FC1);

    double numer    = 0.0, denom = 0.0;
    double _I       = 0.0, _T = 0.0;

    // Defining an image with original world corners in world coordinates "This image will be used as a template for Norm-cross-correl."
    for(int i = 0; i < phy_corners[0].size(); ++i){
            T.at<float>(phy_corners[0][i].x , phy_corners[0][i].y) = 255;
    }

    // Defining an image with Harris detected corners in image coordinates "This image will be used for Norm-cross-correl."
    for(int i = 0; i < img_corners[0].size(); ++i){
            I.at<float>(img_corners[0][i].y , img_corners[0][i].x) = 255;
    }


    /******** NCC-COMPUTATION *******/

    for (int i = idx_y; i < (img.rows - idx_y); ++i){
            for (int j = idx_x ; j < (img.cols - idx_x); ++j){

                    for (int k = -idx_y; k <= idx_y; ++k){
                            for (int l = -idx_x; l <= idx_x; ++l){

                                    _I += I.at<float>(i+k, j+l);
                                    _T += T.at<float>(idx_y+k, idx_x+l);

                            }
                    }

                    _I /= (window.width * window.height);
                    _T /= (window.width * window.height);

                    for (int k = -idx_y; k <= idx_y; ++k){
                            for (int l = -idx_x; l <= idx_x; ++l){

                                    numer += (I.at<float>(i+k,j+l) - _I)*(T.at<float>(idx_y + k,idx_x + l) - _T);

                                    denom += pow((I.at<float>(i+k,j+l) - _I), 2)*pow((T.at<float>(idx_y + k,idx_x + l) - _T),2);
                                    denom = sqrt(denom);
                            }
                    }

                    NCC.at<double>(i-idx_y,j-idx_x) = (numer) / (denom) ;

            }
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes. Generally the top-left first corner of the checkerboard is set to be (0,0,0) in XYZ.

Comment: @AnderBiguri , Sorry for the late reply had been busy working on harris corner detection algorithm, I get what you mean but i'm stuck with the part where I have the harris corners with subpixel accuracy with a bit of false corners, what I am doing is defining a 400*250 matrix with values of 255 at (0,0) ,(50,50), (0,50), (50,0).... and so on as my world co-ordinates (X,Y,Z=0) and using normalized cross correlation to find point correspondences by using the self defined matrix as template and the one generated by the harris corner algorithm as the Image(720 x 1280)...is my logic wrong here?

Comment: The code is too complex to be able to understand in a single comment.

Comment: @AnderBiguri , I have edited the question and provided the code snippet for calculating pt. correspondences based on normalized cross correlation calculations, I hope this can be of some help. Thanks :)